# How to select and get all the values of rows and columns of Table in React js on Click and pass it to other Component...Help Me im stuck in this

Tags: reactjs, html-table, next.js

So I have Created Custom Table Component for my data to show and i want to get all the rows value with the Heading on Click of it and pass it to any component

This is COde of my table Component

```
import PlaceBett from "./PlaceBett";

const MatchBetTable = ({ data }) => {
  const [showPlaceBet, setShowPlaceBet] = useState(false);

  const [team1Back, setTeam1Back] = useState("");
  const [team1Lay, setTeam1Lay] = useState("");
  const [team2Lay, setTeam2Lay] = useState("");
  const [team2Back, setTeam2Back] = useState("");
  const [drawLay, SetDrawLay] = useState("");
  const [drawBack, SetDrawBack] = useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowPlaceBet((prev) => !prev);
  };

  // console.log(data.values[0].val1);
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      {showPlaceBet && (
        <PlaceBett
          data={data}
          team1Back={team1Back}
          team1Lay={team1Lay}
          team2Back={team2Back}
          team2Lay={team2Lay}
          drawBack={drawBack}
          drawLay={drawLay}
        />
      )}

      <table className="table-auto  mb-4 text-black w-full ">
        <thead className="bg-gray-500 md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">
          <tr>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">{data.name}</th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm" colSpan="5"></th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">BET DELAY-3 SEC</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
          <tr
            className="bg-white md:p-5 p-1  text-sm border border-table_border"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">MAX 50000</th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm" colSpan="2"></th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border  ">
              BACK <p>(Back)</p>
            </th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm text-black bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
              LAY <p>(lay)</p>
            </th>
            <th className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm" colSpan="2"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm border border-table_border text-center">
            <td className="bg-gray-300 md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">
              {data.values[0].val1 === null ? "-" : data.values[0].val1}
            </td>
            <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border">
              -<p>(-)</p>
            </td>
            <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
              -<p>(-)</p>
            </td>
            <td
              dataTitle={data.values[0].odds}
              className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border "
              onClick={(e) => {
                console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
                setTeam1Back(e.target.innerHTML);
                console.log("team1Back", team1Back);
              }}
            >
              {data.values[0].odds === null ? "-" : data.values[0].odds}
            </td>

            {/* {!data.values.odds && (
                <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                  0<p>(-)</p>
                </td>
              )} */}

            <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border ">
              {data.values[0].val2 === null ? 0 : data.values[0]?.val2}
            </td>
            <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border ">
              -<p>(-)</p>
            </td>
            <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border ">
              -<p>(-)</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          {data.values[1] && (
            <tr className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm border border-table_border text-center">
              <td className="bg-gray-300 md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">
                {data.values[1]?.val1}
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>

              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1 odd:bg-table_row-cream  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => SetDrawBack(e.target.value)}
              >
                {data.values[1]?.odds}
              </td>
              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => SetDrawLay(e.target.value)}
              >
                {data.values[1]?.val2 === null && "0"}
                {data.values[1]?.val2 && data.values[1]?.val2}
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          )}
          {data?.values[2] && (
            <tr className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm border border-table_border text-center">
              <td className="bg-gray-300 md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">
                {data?.values[2] && data.values[2]?.val1}
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>

              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1 odd:bg-table_row-cream  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => setTeam2Back(e.target.value)}
              >
                {data?.values[2] && data.values[2]?.odds}
              </td>
              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => setTeam2Lay(e.target.value)}
              >
                {data.values[2]?.val2 === null && "0"}
                {data.values[2]?.val2 && data.values[2]?.val2}
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default MatchBetTable;
```

i want the values in state like i used Team1Back and Team1Lay...and pass it to the placeBet Component after clicking particular row...

Comment: You can try some thing like this place the click event on the Table  `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e,data)}` on the handleClick Function with event you can access the Dom eg: e.target.element and find the values or use the data object as you need @vikashkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you do something like this?

```
 <>
          {data.values.map((bet) => (
            <tr className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm border border-table_border text-center">
              <td className="bg-gray-300 md:p-5 p-1  text-sm">{bet?.val1}</td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
    
              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1 odd:bg-table_row-cream  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => SetDrawBack(e.target.value)}
              >
                {bet?.odds}
              </td>
              <td
                className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border"
                onClick={(e) => SetDrawLay(e.target.value)}
              >
                {bet.val2 === null && "0"}
                {bet.val2 && bet?.val2}
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-cream border border-table_border">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </>
```

Comment: ok let me try this..

Comment: how did it go? :D

Answer (score 0):

Use .map instead of data[0], data[1]... then add onClick to row and pass whole object from map

Comment: is there any method to get the values onClick without using Map bcz ...i cant use .map() meththod in this table as some of the values are blank...and not coming from API.. ?

Comment: Can you show me example values? you can map even if some values are blank

Comment: like in my code 
`<td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>
              <td className="md:p-5 p-1  text-sm  bg-table_row-blue border border-table_border ">
                -<p>(-)</p>
              </td>` 
these rows have no values bcz these are not available in API but need to show these rows in Frontend

Comment: I post another answer because couldnt answer this, dont know why